# Trouble populating state via axios

Tags: reactjs, flux, axios

I am trying to use a homespun json API (json-server --watch db.json) to populate the state of a flux store.  I am calling a function of the store from a parent component's `componentWillMount` to load the data with Axios.

I have been looking at the following tutorials for reference:
http://mediatemple.net/blog/tips/loading-and-using-external-data-in-react/
https://www.toptal.com/react/tips-and-practices
and others.

Here is the JSON data I am pulling in:

```
[
  {
    "complete": "false",
    "edit": "false",
    "id": "uuid()",
    "text": "Go Shopping"
  },
  {
    "complete": "false",
    "edit": "false",
    "id": "uuid()",
    "text": "Pay Water Bill"
  }
]
```

db.json gist https://gist.github.com/WebRuin/548f6073ca533016503d34c36116b8de

Here is an excerpt of the Flux store I am calling:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'
import dispatcher from '../dispatcher'
import axios from 'axios'

import uuid from 'uuid4'

class TodoStore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      showCompletedTodos: true,
      showIncompletedTodos: true
    }

    this.deleteTodo = this.deleteTodo.bind(this)
    this.toggleTodo = this.toggleTodo.bind(this)
    this.toggleShowCompletedTodos = this.toggleShowCompletedTodos.bind(this)
    this.toggleShowIncompletedTodos = this.toggleShowIncompletedTodos.bind(this)
  }
...

fetchUserState() {
    let th = this
    console.log(th)
    this.serverRequest = 
      axios.get('http://localhost:3000/todos')
        .then(function(result) {
          console.log(result.data)
          th.state.todos = result.data
        })
  }

}

const todoStore = new TodoStore
dispatcher.register(todoStore.handleActions.bind(todoStore))

export default todoStore
```

Gist of the full file:
https://gist.github.com/WebRuin/efbbf4296c566f6eb58cc6d641bee4ba

Console logging gives shows me that the axios request is fulfilled with the data I want and a log of `this` shows that `this.state.todos` is being populated, but the react plugin of Chrome does not show the data and hence the app does not display the data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of "th.state.todos = result.data", try "th.setState({ todos: result.data })"

Comment: Very good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andy is right, except the constructor, we should always use `setState()` that works asynchronously when setting the state.

---

From [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html): [1](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) and [2](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

---

However, this is true for the common React. In Flux we should forget the `setState` method and just work with the stores. This is the message from the article.

I created one image for my Flux navigation, it may help you.

[image]

---

Typically you should load the data via axios, not via the `componentWillMount()`, but you may use Flux actions flow for that.
But still, you can use `componentWillMount()` to create the action.

Comment: This adds a great perspective.  Thanks, still not sure though how to use this.setState from a store created with EventEmiter

Comment: Git hub it. There should be examples @Tithos

Comment: I meant to say search the github for solution @Tithos . It may help.

Answer (score 1):

Never modify the state object directly. Always use `setState()`.

Comment: `this.setState` can be called from `EventEmitter`.  I have run into that before.  In my limited experience, `this.setState` can only be called from `React.Component' or 'React.creatClass'

Comment: `this.setState` can not be called from `EventEmitter` I mean

Comment: Your code modifies state inside `fetchUserState ` which is on the component class

Comment: Here is what I get when I try this `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: th.setState is not a function at TodoStore.js:58'